# D3.json function to return only some of json file data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am reading csv file using `d3.csv` which works fine. Reading csv file also renames columns with a function:

However, I would rather read same data from a json file.

```
d3.csv("myfile.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        location: d.identifier,
        date: new Date(d.created),
        amount: d.count_objects
        };
}).then(function getData(rawData) {

    console.log(rawData[0]);        

});
```

The console output from `d3.csv` returns results with renamed columns:

```
console:

{location: "CO", date: Wed Jan 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), amount: "0"}
```

I just swapped out csv for json file in same code, expecting it to be read similarly but it isn't.

```
d3.json("myfile.json", function(d) {
    return {
        location: d.identifier,
        date: new Date(d.created),
        amount: d.count_objects
        };
}).then(function getData(rawData) {

    console.log(rawData[0]);
    
});
```

However, the console output from `d3.json` returns results with orignal json keys:

```
console:

{created: "2020-01-22T00:00:00.000", identifier: "CO", count_objects: "0"}
```

What modifications are required for `d3.json()` to get same results with `d3.csv()` eg to return results with renamed keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) doesn't use a row function, since json data isn't always an array. To processes the data, you can do something like:

```
d3.json("myfile.json").then(function (json) {
    return json.map(function (d) {
        return {
            location: d.identifier,
            date: new Date(d.created),
            amount: d.count_objects
        };
    });
}).then(function getData(rawData) {

    console.log(rawData[0]);
    
});
```